# Is it possible to return a previously returned variable?

Tags: c#, methods

I am working on a Guessing Game of sorts for a project at school, but am running into a problem when trying to return a previously returned variable. I am unsure whether or not this is because I haven't finished the program, or whether this is something I've overlooked. The point of the exercise is to generate and use specific methods based on given parameters, otherwise I would have written my current code much differently.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdvGuessNumber
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        static string Input(string promptString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(promptString);
            string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            return inputString;
        }
        static int IntInput(string promptString)
        {
            bool isIntInput = false;
            Console.WriteLine(promptString);
            while (isIntInput == false){
                try
                {
                    Input(promptString);
                    inputInt = Convert.ToInt32(inputString);
                    isIntInput = true;
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    isIntInput = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return inputInt;

        }
        static int GenerateNumber()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.Next(1, 100);
            return n;
        }
        static int GetGuess()
        {
            IntInput("Please enter an integer");
            return inputInt; //Trying to reference this from IntInput method


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some clarity to your question - for example what error message or incorrect behavior are you getting?

Comment: The keyword `return` instructs a method to return back to the caller of that method. `return something` means the value of `something` will be returned to the caller when the method returns to the caller. (Hence why the keyword is called `return`...) If the caller needs/wants to do something with the returned value, the caller can assign the value returned by the called method to a variable like `var returnValue = someMethod(...);`, for example...

Comment: @Symon I knew the main was empty, I have just started. And that was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: The same you have asigned the return of the function `Console.ReadLine()` in this line `string inputString = Console.ReadLine();` you could do inside the  `GetGuess` function. Something like `int guessedValue = IntInput("Please enter an integer");` and later `return guessedValue;`

Comment: FYI, your `IntInput` method can be reduced to 3 lines, and using `int.TryParse` is far more efficient than using `try/catch` for validation: `int inputInt; while (!int.TryParse(Input(promptString), out inputInt)); return inputInt;`

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your question correctly, you can just:

```
    static int GetGuess()
    {
        return IntInput("Please enter an integer");
    }
```

If you need to do something after `IntInput`, you can store the value in a variable first:

```
    static int GetGuess()
    {
        int value = IntInput("Please enter an integer");

        // Do something else here...

        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether or not a return value can be passed from one method to another, the answer is yes! In fact this is exactly how [recursion](https://code-maze.com/csharp-basics-recursion/) works, where a method calls itself until a known condition is reached, and then the call stack unwinds and the return values are passed back through all the calls until it gets to the original caller.

Here's an example that shows how one method uses the return value of another method in it's operation. Notice that `GetInt` calls `GetString` inside the `while` condition, and if the string returned can't be converted to an `int`, then `int.TryParse` fails, and the `while` condition is executed again and again (until `int.TryParse` passes, after which the variable `result` holds the converted value):

```
static string GetString(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return Console.ReadLine(); // Return the result of the call to ReadLine directly
}

static int GetInt(string prompt)
{
    int result;
    while (!int.TryParse(GetString(prompt), out result)) ; // Empty while loop body
    return result;
}
```

Here's another sample with lots of this kind of interaction:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly Random Rnd = new Random();

    private static string GetString(string prompt)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int GetInt(string prompt)
    {
        int result;
        while (!int.TryParse(GetString(prompt), out result)) ;
        return result;
    }

    private static ConsoleKeyInfo GetKey(string prompt)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        return Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool PlayGame()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Guessing Game");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------");
        Console.WriteLine("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.");
        Console.WriteLine("Let's see how many guesses it takes you to find it!\n");

        int input, guesses = 0, myNumber = Rnd.Next(1, 101);
        var message = "Enter your guess (or '0' to quit): ";

        for (input = GetInt(message);            // Initialize input to user's value
            input != 0 && input != myNumber;     // Iterate until they get it or enter 0
            input = GetInt(message), guesses++)  // Get a new value on each iteration
        {
            Console.WriteLine(input < myNumber ? "Too low!" : "Too high!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(input == myNumber
            ? $"Correct! That took {guesses} guesses."
            : $"Sorry you didn't get it! The number was: {myNumber}.");

        // Here we call Equals directly on the result of GetString
        return GetString("\nDo you want to play again (y/n)? ")
            .Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        while (PlayGame()) ; // Empty while loop body - keeps looping until they say "no"
        GetKey("Done! Press any key to exit...");
    }
}
```